# How to Call a java function in JSF navigation throgh <to-view-id>

Tags: jsf-2

```
<navigation-case>
<from-action>#{tabViewController.openscreen}</from-action>
<from-outcome>Group Master</from-outcome>
<to-view-id>#{tabViewController.openscreen1}</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

in the , i want to call a java function because i need to open a screen in tab controller.

Comment: I don't understand the question, perhaps you might be able to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you come from a framework that has this functionality? As in Pageflows from seam.

JSF-2.0 does not have this afaik. But if I understand you correctly you want to execute a method when a view gets loaded.

This is usually done with either:

```
<f:event listener="#{user.isAdmin}" type="preRenderView" />
```

full example:  http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-prerenderviewevent-example/

Or by using JSR-250 and the annotation `@PostConstruct`.

A method annotated with it will be executed after injections and it's a very useful annotation for your use case and afaik it's best practice in most cases.

Good luck.